# Sum of Lebesgue integral (absolutely integrable functions)

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

This is Tao Analysis II Prop. 19.3.3. (b)

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ measurable and $f,g: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ absolutely integrable functions. Then $f+g$ is absolutely integrable and 
$$
\int_\Omega f+g = \int_\Omega f + \int_\Omega g
$$

How can I prove that ?

My  first idea was $f+g = f^+ + g^+ - (f^- + g^-)$. But then  I get a problem with "$-$"-sign.

Comment: well, you can show that $(f+g)^+\leq f^+ + g^+$ and the same for the negative parts - just using the properties of the $\max$ function. That gives you the integrability.

Comment: Yes. This was the easy part :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from [Folland, Proposition 2.21](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160). Let $h = f+g$, then we know that
$$
  h^+ - h^- = f^++g^+-(f^-+g^-)
$$
and by regrouping
$$
  h^+ + f^-+g^- = h^- + f^++g^+.
$$
Since all functions are positive,
$$
  \int h^+ + \int f^-+\int g^- = \int h^- + \int f^++\int g^+
$$
and thus
$$
  \int h^+ - \int h^- = \int f^++\int g^+-\int f^--\int g^- =\int f - \int g
$$

Comment: In other words, you should first prove your result for nonnegative functions.

Comment: @GEdgar: for them it follows directly from the linearity for simple functions and the definition of the integral. It seems from OP, that OP doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks. Quite simple indeed.